# Why text is not showing in a gradient Button?

Tags: c#, styles, gradient, winapp

I use the below code to set a gradient to a button in a windows form. It works but it's Text is not showing. What should I do to fix it?
Thank you.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       button2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Button2_Paint);
 }
 private void Button2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
      Graphics g = e.Graphics;
      g.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty, new PointF(button2.Width, button2.Height), Color.Pink, Color.Red), new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, button2.Size));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you never actually drawing that text. Currently you only filling button's client rectangle with gradient, but there is no any text within. To show the string with button's text you need to add some more lines to Paint method:

```
 private void Button2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
    Button btn= (Button)sender;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty, new PointF(button2.Width, button2.Height), Color.Pink, Color.Red), new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, button2.Size));
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(btn.Text, btn.Font);
    PointF topLeft = new PointF(btn.Width / 2 - size.Width / 2, btn.Height / 2 - size.Height / 2);
    g.DrawString(btn.Text, btn.Font, Brushes.Black, topLeft);
  }
```

Here [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) gives you the width and height of a button's Text property, these values are used to position text right in the middle of a button. And [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx) just draws the string with supplied color, font and position.